# Stop GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP from connecting last and first vertex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pyglet

I have been trying to build a Terrain Visualizer from OpenGL and using a height map from simplex noise. I have the generator all sorted and it produces both colored and non-colored images, I only want to visualized the colored ones. However there is this weird bump thing, that I believe is a result of GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP.

Picture of the artifact, oddities outlined in red:

[image: Picture of the artifact]

My best guess is GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP attaching the first and last vertex, but I do not know.

Here is my code:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
from pyglet.window import key
import math
from PIL import Image

class Model:
    def get_points_in_list(self, fp):
        img = Image.open(fp)
        self.points = [[0 for x in range(img.width)] for y in range(img.height)]
        for y in range(img.height):
            for x in range(img.width):
                self.points[y][x] = ((x, img.getpixel((x, y))[3], y), img.getpixel((x, y)))

    def add_points_to_batch(self):
        ysiz = len(self.points)
        xsiz = len(self.points[0])
        # color1[0], color1[1], color1[2], color2[0], color2[1], color2[2]
        for yy in range(ysiz-1):
            for xx in range(xsiz):
                pos = self.points[yy][xx][0]
                x, y, z = pos[0], pos[1], pos[2]
                pos1 = self.points[yy+1][xx][0]
                X, Y, Z = pos1[0], pos1[1], pos1[2]

                color1 = (self.points[yy][xx][1][0], self.points[yy][xx][1][1], self.points[yy][xx][1][2])
                color2 = (self.points[yy+1][xx][1][0], self.points[yy+1][xx][1][1], self.points[yy+1][xx][1][2])
                self.batch.add(2, GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, None,
                               ('v3f', (x, y, z, X, Y, Z)),
                               ('c3B', (color1[0], color1[1], color1[2], color2[0], color2[1], color2[2]))
                               )

    def __init__(self):
        self.batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
        self.points = None
        self.get_points_in_list('Output_colored.png')
        self.add_points_to_batch()

    def draw(self):
        self.batch.draw()

class Player:
    def __init__(self, pos=(0, 0, 0), rot=(0, 0)):
        self.pos = list(pos)
        self.rot = list(rot)

    def mouse_motion(self, dx, dy):
        dx /= 8
        dy /= 8
        self.rot[0] += dy
        self.rot[1] -= dx
        if self.rot[0]>90:
            self.rot[0] = 90
        elif self.rot[0] < -90:
            self.rot[0] = -90

    def update(self,dt,keys):
        sens = 1
        s = dt*100
        rotY = -self.rot[1]/180*math.pi
        dx, dz = s*math.sin(rotY), math.cos(rotY)
        if keys[key.W]:
            self.pos[0] += dx*sens
            self.pos[2] -= dz*sens
        if keys[key.S]:
            self.pos[0] -= dx*sens
            self.pos[2] += dz*sens
        if keys[key.A]:
            self.pos[0] -= dz*sens
            self.pos[2] -= dx*sens
        if keys[key.D]:
            self.pos[0] += dz*sens
            self.pos[2] += dx*sens
        if keys[key.SPACE]:
            self.pos[1] += s
        if keys[key.LSHIFT]:
            self.pos[1] -= s

class Window(pyglet.window.Window):

    def push(self,pos,rot):
        glPushMatrix()
        rot = self.player.rot
        pos = self.player.pos
        glRotatef(-rot[0],1,0,0)
        glRotatef(-rot[1],0,1,0)
        glTranslatef(-pos[0], -pos[1], -pos[2])

    def Projection(self):
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()

    def Model(self):
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()

    def set2d(self):
        self.Projection()
        gluPerspective(0, self.width, 0, self.height)
        self.Model()

    def set3d(self):
        self.Projection()
        gluPerspective(70, self.width/self.height, 0.05, 1000)
        self.Model()

    def setLock(self, state):
        self.lock = state
        self.set_exclusive_mouse(state)

    lock = False
    mouse_lock = property(lambda self:self.lock, setLock)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_minimum_size(300,200)
        self.keys = key.KeyStateHandler()
        self.push_handlers(self.keys)
        pyglet.clock.schedule(self.update)

        self.model = Model()
        self.player = Player((0.5,1.5,1.5),(-30,0))

    def on_mouse_motion(self,x,y,dx,dy):
        if self.mouse_lock: self.player.mouse_motion(dx,dy)

    def on_key_press(self, KEY, _MOD):
        if KEY == key.ESCAPE:
            self.close()
        elif KEY == key.E:
            self.mouse_lock = not self.mouse_lock

    def update(self, dt):
        self.player.update(dt, self.keys)

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.set3d()
        self.push(self.player.pos,self.player.rot)
        self.model.draw()
        glPopMatrix()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Window(width=400, height=300, caption='Terrain Viewer', resizable=True)
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    pyglet.app.run()
```